# Identifying coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, north-america

I have come across a northing and easting type of system that I can not identify or convert. It seems like UTM but is not. This is an example of a coordinate that I have:

```
N4738272.047
E712167.899
```

The corresponding lat and lon would be 42.767626, -78.406808. This is a known position but I have several positions that I am trying to convert.

Answer (score 1):

These coordinates are in UTM Zone 17N. So depending on the datum, your coordinates should correspond to one of the following coordinate reference systems:

- [EPSG:26917](https://epsg.io/26917) - NAD83 / UTM Zone 17N
- [EPSG:6346](https://epsg.io/6346) - NAD83(2011) / UTM zone 17N
- [EPSG:3747](https://epsg.io/3747) - NAD83(HARN) / UTM zone 17N
- [EPSG:3724](https://epsg.io/3724) - NAD83(NSRS2007) / UTM zone 17N
- [EPSG:32617](https://epsg.io/32617) - WGS 84 / UTM zone 17N

Answer (score 0):

These look like coordinates for New York State Plane West (Feet).
https://epsg.io/2262